# How to join column names in a table with a row index of another table

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a dataframe of time series data where the column names are the ID of index:

```
data = {'HFRXGL Index': [0.35, 1.1, 0.3, 2.6],
        'BCOMTR Index': [1.35, 2.1, 4.3, 5.6],
        'GOLDLNPM Index': [0.34, 0.15, 0.17, 1.15]}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then i have another dataframe where i have the description of index

```
data_b = {'index_id': ['HFRXGL Index',"BCOMTR Index", "GOLDLNPM Index"],
            'Index Description': ["HFRX Global Hedge Fund Index", "Bloomberg Commodity Index Total Return", "LBMA Gold Price PM USD"]}

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b)
```

I need to join the two dataframes on column names of df_a and index_id of df_b in order to obtain the index description contained in df_b

Comment: can you give us an example of your desired output ?

Comment: Can you please provide and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert columns to rows in the `df_a` dataframe using [transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html). Then [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by indexes: `df_a.index` and `'index_id'` columns.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # print everything rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # print everything columns

df_a = df_a.transpose()

df_a = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, left_on=df_a.index, right_on='index_id')

print(df_a)
```

Output

```
      0     1     2     3        index_id  \
0  0.35  1.10  0.30  2.60    HFRXGL Index   
1  1.35  2.10  4.30  5.60    BCOMTR Index   
2  0.34  0.15  0.17  1.15  GOLDLNPM Index   

                        Index Description  
0            HFRX Global Hedge Fund Index  
1  Bloomberg Commodity Index Total Return  
2                  LBMA Gold Price PM USD
```